# Parsing changing tags BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If my tags keep on changing as follows:

```
<tr id="CN13FUT">
<tr id="CU13FUT">
<tr id="CZ13FUT">
<tr id="CH14FUT">
[...]
```

How can I read this in using BeautifulSoup?
This is what I need help with:

```
table = BeautifulSoup(page)
for tr in table.findAll('tr', attrs = {'id': 'something_here'))
   print tr
```

I don't want to use just `table.findAll('tr')` because there might be other `tr` tags that I don't want, I only want as how it is shown in the format above.

Comment: Do all the `tr`s (the ones you need) have an id? And do they always start with a C?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex pattern to specify which `<tr>`s you want:

```
import bs4 as bs
import re

doc = '''<tr id="CN13FUT">
    <tr id="CU13FUT">
    <tr id="CZ13FUT">
    <tr id="CH14FUT">
    <tr id="ButNotThis">
   '''
table = bs.BeautifulSoup(doc)
for tr in table.findAll(id=re.compile(r'CN13|CU13|CZ13|CH14')):
    print(tr)
```

yields

```
<tr id="CN13FUT">
</tr>
<tr id="CU13FUT">
</tr>
<tr id="CZ13FUT">
</tr>
<tr id="CH14FUT">
</tr>
```

Comment: But what if I didn't know how many tags `<tr> id=...` were? Maybe it would be easier to read all `tr` tags and parse the correct ones.

Comment: My solution does not require that you know the *number* of tags. It is only meant to show the *form* of an answer based on using a regex pattern to select the desired `tr` tags. You never stated the criterion for selecting the desired `tr` tags, so I assume you know how to form the right regex pattern. If you don't you need to state the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

If all id attributes are ending in "FUT", then

```
for tr in table.findAll(id=re.compile('FUT$')):
    print(tr)
    print(tr['id']) # to print the id attributes
```

If all id attributes are the same length (7), then

```
for tr in table.findAll('tr', id=lambda x: x and len(x)==7):
    print(tr['id']) # to print the id attributes
```