# BeautifulSoup Detect Change Trigger

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a script that uses bs4 to scrape a webpage and grab a string named, "Last Updated 4/3/2020, 8:28 p.m.". I then assign this string to a variable and send it in an email. The script is scheduled to run once a day. However, the date and time on the website change every other day. So, instead of emailing every time I run the script I'd like to set up a trigger so that it sends only when the date is different. How do I configure the script to detect that change?

String in HTML:

```
COVID-19 News Updates



Last Updated 4/3/2020, 12:08 p.m.
```

```
'''Checks municipal websites for changes in meal assistance during C19 pandemic'''

# Import requests (to download the page)
import requests
# Import BeautifulSoup (to parse what we download)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#list of urls
urls = ['http://www.vofil.com/covid19_updates']

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

#download the homepage
response = requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers)
#parse the downloaded homepage and grab all text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
#Find string
last_update_fra = soup.findAll(string=re.compile("Last Updated"))
print(last_update_fra)

#Put something here (if else..?) to trigger an email.

#I left off email block...
```

The closet answer I found was this, but it's referring to the tags, not a string.
[Parsing changing tags BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415796/parsing-changing-tags-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to check every so often for a change using something along the lines of this:

```py
'''Checks municipal websites for changes in meal assistance during C19 pandemic'''

# Import requests (to download the page)
import requests
# Import BeautifulSoup (to parse what we download)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time

#list of urls
urls = ['http://www.vofil.com/covid19_updates']

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

while True:
    #download the homepage
    response = requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers)
    #parse the downloaded homepage and grab all text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    #Find string
    last_update_fra = soup.findAll(string=re.compile("Last Updated"))
    time.sleep(60)
    #download request again
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers), "lxml")

    if soup.findAll(string=re.compile("Last Updated")) == last_update_fra:
        continue
    else:
        # Code to send email
*This waits a minute before checking for changes, but it can be adjusted as needed.
[Credit][1]: https://chrisalbon.com/python/web_scraping/monitor_a_website/
```

Comment: I'd imagine Windows Task Scheduler could be used in place of the time module?

Comment: The code you posted is throwing an error on the second soup variable:
```line 275, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()```

Comment: My apologies for the late response, in the second BeautifulSoup object  you should have `requests.get(urls[0], headers=headers).text` as the first argument

Comment: I left that off and Windows Task Scheduler is a possibility if you could figure something out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Adding ```.text``` to the first argument did the trick. However, in my case I think Task Scheduler is the better option. So, what I did is take it out of the while loop and remove the time module. It still works fine. You pretty much gave the correct answer, but if you don't mind I'm going to wait until that website makes an update (which should be in the next day or two?) so I know for sure if it's working.